# Detect real compile error in visual studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Due to some reason, the visual c++ unable to give a real error. Instead, it will report error happen in correct code.

For example, use third-party library, a particular header file include order might make vs report error happens in some system file(such as mswsock.h) or in user code. It is very hard to find out the real error.

Does there a way to handle this situation? I check the detailed compile log but have not find something is useful. Or the only way is keeping comment out code and compile bit by bit?

Comment: It would be much easier if you posted the exact errors and offending code instead of letting us guess.

Comment: Actually, the error is random. I am look for a generic method rather than solve the current problem. For example, use boost::asio and mongodb, if place mongodb header file ahead of asio, vs will report error happen in asio code. It is very time consuming to find out the real problem.

Comment: no, the error is not random

Comment: your computer is a deterministic machine, and there will be certain conditions that lead to a certain error, and for all these different kinds of errors, there's different reasons.

Comment: and "the real reason" for why your compiler fails is what your tells you. However, someone **might** have made a human mistake, and tracking that down needs case-to-case consideration, analysis, experience and understanding.

Comment: I mean there are a lot of ways to generate this kind problem, of course for an specified problem, that will not random, each time you compile, you gets same error

Comment: "vs will report error happen in asio code". There are tens, if not hundreds, of compiler and linker errors defined by VS toolset. Guessing the right one requires psychic powers if there is just a vague description of a problem (and often people describe their opinion and not the real problem). Error info (from Output, not ErrorsAndWarnings window) would be very helpful.

Comment: and jean, there's now three persons that tell you that it depends, and there's no "general magic" to do to understand an error. There really is no "realer" reason than what the compiler says- there might be **underlying issues**, but finding them requires understanding **of each specific error**, the **tools** and **languages** involved and a bit of experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS will almost certainly tell you the exact point *where it failed*. Now, that line of code might not be the point where a logical error was made, but it's the point where compilation failed. That's what the compiler knows.

So obviously, the answer depends on the error, the libraries and their headers, and a lot more.

So, to answer your question:

> Does there a way to handle this situation?

Investigate. Build up experience. Become better at asking questions.

Comment: Does detail compile log help? For a link error, the link log can show something. But the compile log seems helpless. The only way I can use is bit by bit comment out my code til compile pass so I can find the last comment out content is the source of problem, but it is very time consuming, painful

Comment: usually, you just go through all the compiler errors from top to bottom, and understand the reason for each, fix it, recompile, move on to the next error and so on.